# Fastest way to read user input in Ruby

Tags: ruby, io

I have some time now and I do some challenges from SPOJ in Ruby. One think that bothers me is how I read user input faster.

For example, this problem: http://www.spoj.com/problems/TEST/

I have tried many solutions, all based on gets:

```
while ((i=STDIN.gets.to_i) != 42) do
 puts i
end

$stdin.each_line do |line|
  exit if line.strip! == "42"
  puts line
end

def input
 while (true)
  gets
  exit if ($_.chomp == "42")
  puts $_.chomp
 end
end
input
```

and other variations with gets. Best time that I get is 0.01s and memory footprint of 7.2 Mb. But looking at best submissions using Ruby language first 5 pages are all 0.00s and 3.1Mb of memory used.

Any idea how I can get the input faster? 
Also all the tests there are using STDIN to pass the test cases to the app, some very large (hundreds of Mb) and I suspect that gets is too slow for reading that kind of input (or chomp might be). Is some other way faster than gets?

Comment: You know parentheses aren't necessary for method arguments, right? Do you just prefer to have them?

Comment: How about using Readline? http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/readline/rdoc/Readline.html

Comment: @DylanRichards I've always used parentheses since it looks clearer to me.

Comment: have you tried ARGF http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ARGF.html

Comment: As far as 3.1MB, look at when they were submitted, all the submissions < 7.2MB are at the top, even when sorted by submission date. If it was something we, the programmers, could control, you'd see lower values interspersed throughout.

Comment: Simplest way (and fast enough for me, `0.01`): `print until gets.strip == '42'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get 0.0 times by keeping the code simple and knowing what's going to be a faster way to do things. I won't show my code, because people are supposed to figure out the problem on their own:

```
while ((i=STDIN.gets.to_i) != 42) do
 puts i
end
```

Ugh. Don't convert from the retrieved string to an integer just to compare it to `42`. Instead compare to `'42'`, though, remember, you *could* be getting trailing line-endings on the strings.

```
$stdin.each_line do |line|
  exit if line.strip! == "42"
  puts line
end
```

Again, don't `strip`, instead use a smarter comparison. Also, `strip!` *could* bite you if nothing changed in the string by returning nil instead of the string you're expecting. I'd use `strip` instead, because it'd is guaranteed to return the expected value.

```
def input
 while (true)
  gets
  exit if ($_.chomp == "42")
  puts $_.chomp
 end
end
input
```

Two `chomp` are costly. You should `$_.chomp!` separately.

Something to know, Ruby's regular expression engine is very fast, and an anchored regular expression pattern will outrun a regular instring search.

Test your code variations using Ruby's Benchmark class and you can narrow down which differences help.

I have one version that uses a loop, very similar to your middle solution, and another that's a single line of code. Both were 0.0 sec.

Comment: I am not interested in solution for that problem, was just an example. I am interested to know how I read the input. Is gets fast enough for large inputs? Are there any faster ways to read it?

Comment: Define "fast enough". You can `read` all at once, then have to convert to an array to iterate over the data. `read_lines` does that for you but doesn't speed up the overall processing. In my testing `foreach` and `each_line` are very fast, and avoid the "slurp" and "split". Benchmarks are the way to tell for sure.